# path correct but include not found

Tags: c++, path, include

OS: win7, gcc++
I have set:

```
AWE_DIR=C:\Program Files (x86)\Awesomium Technologies LLC\Awesomium SDK\1.7.3.0\
```

and it's been displayed like this when I call "SET". 
But when I try to compile my code

```
 #include <C:\Program Files (x86)\Awesomium Technologies LLC\Awesomium SDK\1.7.3.0\include\Awesomium\WebCore.h>
```

is working, but:

```
 #include <$(AWE_DIR)include\Awesomium\WebCore.h>
```

is not working. (include\Awesomium\WebCore.h: No such file or directory)

Whats am I doing wrong? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AWE_DIR` is an environment variable. Your compiler doesn't know anything about environment variables when looking for include files. It shouldn't.

Instead you can add `C:\Program Files (x86)\Awesomium Technologies LLC\Awesomium SDK\1.7.3.0\include` to the include path in the compiler options (using -I) and then use

`#include <Awesomium\WebCore.h>`

(without the ugly leading include btw). Surely this should be described in the Awesomium docs?

**edit** quickly checked the docs and there is not much on using Awesomium with gcc, only [with VS](http://wiki.awesomium.com/getting-started/setting-up-on-windows.html). Also you can just use `$(AWE_DIR)\include` or `%AWE_DIR%\include` etc with -I since when invoking gcc you're in some kind of command line environment which *does* know environment variables and does expand them.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was expecting to the compiler to expand $(AWE_DIR)

Comment: the compiler itself won't, but the build system should, see update.

Comment: It seems that Awesomium will only work with VS. I'll have to look elsewhere for a html UI.

Answer (score 0):

The c++ preprocessor doesn't expand shell variables! Try using the -I option, and omit the path.